# How do display a secondary menu within a drupal node without the node displaying as a actual menu item

Tags: routes, navigation

I have created a menu with a teaser view with the teasers linking further to nodes.  The problem I have is I would like the secondary navigation to continue to persist with the node that the teaser page links to.  The secondary navigation always drops when I go to the actual node. However I don't want these nodes to be menu items. How do you keep a node within the secondary navigation structure without making it an actual menu item?

Answer (score 1):

I found a great module that seems to work great!  It's called menu position found here: http://drupal.org/project/menu_position and it's super easy to use.